# Is it possible to map species occurrence points in R when only have OS 6 figure grid refs?

Tags: r, mapping, coordinates

I have a relatively large-ish (>4,000 records) dataset of species records that needs to be mapped in R, however the only spatial information with them are 6 figure Ordnance Survey’s National Grid (NGR) format grid references (e.g. SD311124, see also [A beginners guide to finding grid references](https://getoutside.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/guides/beginners-guide-to-grid-references/)). The file format is CSV.

How can I get R to plot the points with this information?

Is there a better way to do it within R rather than bulk converting and adding lat/long coords to the spreadsheet before loading it into R?

I know how to do this in QGIS, but my supervisors would like it in R instead!

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/10/converting-british-national-grid-references/